# React native send a message to specific whatsapp Group

Tags: reactjs, native, whatsapp

For my react Native project i would like a button that open whatsapp on phone directly on a specific group and not just a number , i can't find it on the whatsapp docs ,

If someone got an idea ,

Thanks

`onPress={() => { Linking.openURL("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?name=Familizz"); }}`

Here name = Groupe and not just someone